# Sorting a User type by updatedAt using PrimaryKey and sortFieldKey throws error: The primary key on type 'User' must reference non-null fields

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I am trying to have amplify sort my users by updatedAt date, so when I use listUsers.limit(20) it returns 20 of the most recent ones. I added a sortkeyfield to the primaryKey:

```
id: ID! @primaryKey(sortKeyFields: ["updatedAt"])
```

But when I ran this I received the error: `An error occurred during the push operation: The primary key on type 'User' must reference non-null fields.`

This was the only change on amplify, so I am not sure why it threw this error. Most of the docs online and problem shooting revolve around the old @key directive, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer. You need to set the updatedAt field to required. So it should look like: updatedAt: AWSDATETIME!